# Problems inner join in zend 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I try to do a join in the following way but I can not, that I'm wrong? use zend 1.12

```
SELECT al.nombre, ar.nombre FROM `album` AS al
INNER JOIN artista AS ar ON al.artista_id = ar.id
```

```
$select = $this->select()
         ->from(array('al' => 'album'),
                array('id', 'nombre'))
         ->join(array('ar' => 'artista'),
                'al.artista_id = ar.id');
    $rows = $this->fetchAll($select);


    return $rows;
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `but I can not`? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: sorry, appears Message: Select query cannot join with another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `integrity check` flag

```
$select = $this->select()
     ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
     ->from(array('al' => 'album'),
            array('id', 'nombre'))
     ->join(array('ar' => 'artista'),
            'al.artista_id = ar.id');
$rows = $this->fetchAll($select);


return $rows;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

the problem was, you didn't use right object

```
$select = $this->select()
         ->from(array('al' => 'album'),
                array('id', 'nombre'))
         ->join(array('ar' => 'artista'),
                'al.artista_id = ar.id');

    $rows = $select ->query()->fetchAll();


    return $rows;
```

Comment: 1- With no explanation, I hardly noticed the changes between your and his post! 
2- `$rows = $select ->fetchAll($select);` is not correct. You eiter should run 
   1. $rows = $select->query()->fetchAll(); //or
   2. $rows = $this->fetchAll($select); //like he did

Thanks

Comment: true that, forgot the query()